# Swift 3 Passing a closure via selectors to objc functions

Tags: objective-c, swift, function, closures, selector

I want to pass a closure through another function via a selector. Here is what I am trying to do ideally:

```
@objc private func aFunction(_ firstParam: String, onComplete: (String) -> Void) {
    //..some internal codes
    onComplete("Done.")
}

func functionCaller(_ selectorString: String, paramString: String, onComplete: (String) -> Void) {
    let selector : Selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString)

    self.perform(selector, with: printString, with: onComplete)
}

functionCaller("aFunction:onComplete:", paramString: "anotherParameter", onComplete: { (_ myString String) -> Void in
    print(myString)
})
```

Here the problem is when you try to compile this, Swift gives an error called "Segmentation Fault: 11"

I found the problematic line which is:

`self.perform(selector, with: printString, with: onComplete)`

when I change last `with: onComplete` parameter to a String (also changed related functions params) it is working. As far as I understand that the problem is sending closure via `self.perform` call doesn't work because the first function is an '@objc' marked function (I put this because otherwise perform selector did not work on Swift 3).

So any idea how can I pass a function or closure into a '@objc' marked function via performing selector?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Any` instead of `String` in your function

```
func functionCaller(_ selectorString: String, paramString: String, onComplete: (Any) -> Void) {

    let selector : Selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString)
    let complete : Any = onComplete("complete")        
    self.perform(selector, with: complete)
}

functionCaller("aFunction:onComplete:", paramString: "anotherParameter", onComplete: { (_ myString ) -> Void in

    let string = myString as! String
    print(string)
})
```

I tested it and works in **Swift 3**

Comment: When I try this with my condition (there are 2 functions, 1 is middleware 1 is objc and there is one caller), I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS. The difference between your example and mine is I have 2 functions and 1 function caller. (By the way when I changed it to Any as you suggested, just the error changed to EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Comment: And here in your example you decide what to put inside the closure parameter as string in functionCaller `onComplete("complete")` but I want it to passed by the other function that I call with selector (In my example it is called as aFunction)

Answer (score -2):

let completionHandler: (Any) -> Void = { value in
                    let js = "try {(callBackKey)('(value)'); delete window.(callBackKey);} catch(e){};"
                    (jsContext as? TYWKWebView)?.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: nil)
                }

let handlerDict: [String: Any] = [TYJSBridge.COMPLETION_HANDLER_KEY: completionHandler]

let _ = jsInterfaceObject.perform(sel, with: parameters, with: handlerDict)
            }